# Excel VBA error while check logon and logout check using IE

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation

I am amature VBA programmer. I am working in a small automation.
The steps are

1. Open a IE browser
2. Navigate to a webpage
3. Logon using my username and password

I am using below excel VBA code to get my solution

Code snippet

```
Sub LoginAuto()
Dim Myhtml As IHTMLElement
Dim Myurl As String
Myurl = "http://myurl.com"
Set Mybroswer = New InternetExplorer
Mybroswer.Silent = True
Mybroswer.navigate Myurl
Mybroswer.Visible = True

Do
Loop Until Mybroswer.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDOC = Mybroswer.document

HTMLDOC.all.UserName.Value = "myuser"
HTMLDOC.all.Password.Value = "mypassword"

For Each Myhtml In HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("button")
    If Myhtml.Type = "submit" Then
    Myhtml.Click:
    End If
    Exit For
Next
End Sub
```

while running above program i am getting below error

> excel vba automation error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Loop Until Mybroswer.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE  if I comment above line error is on Set HTMLDOC = Mybroswer.document

Comment: You could add `DoEvents` between `Do` and `Loop Until Mybroswer.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE`. For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403210/internet-explorer-vba-automation-error-the-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from). You could also try to use `Do Until ieA.readyState = 4     DoEvents     Loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears,
I am able to resolve my reported problem by using "SHDocVw.InternetExplorer" instead of IHTMLElement

This allows me to "Loop Until Mybroswer.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE"

Answer (score 0):

Is Autoit (www-autoitscript.com) an option for you? It provides lots of useful functions to automate stuff like that.

Try this

```
#include<IE.au3>
$sUsername = "Username"
$sPassword = "Password"
$sUrl = "http://www.yoururl.com"
$oIE = _IECreate($sUrl, 0, 1, 1, 1)
$oHWND = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd")
WinSetState($oHWND, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
$oForm = _IEFormGetCollection ($oIE, 0)
$oUsername = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, 'UserName')
$oPassword = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "Password")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oUsername, $sUsername)
_IEFormElementSetValue($oPassword, $sPassword)
_IEFormSubmit ($oForm)
```